# Solution to host 200GB of data and provide JSON API with aggregates?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

I am looking for a solution that will host a nearly-static 200GB, structured, clean dataset, and provide a JSON API onto the data, for querying in a web app.

Each row of my data looks like this, and I have about 700 million rows:

```
parent_org,org,spend,count,product_code,product_name,date
A31,A81001,1003223.2,14,QX0081,Rosiflora,2014-01-01
```

The data is almost completely static - it updates once a month. I would like to support straightforward aggregate queries like:

- get total spending on product codes starting QX, by organisation, by month
- get total spending by parent org A31, by month

And I would like these queries to be available over a RESTful JSON API, so that I can use the data in a web application.

I don't need to do joins, I only have one table.

Solutions I have investigated:

- To date I have been using Postgres (with a web app to provide the API), but am starting to reach the limits of what I can do with indexing and materialized views, without dedicated hardware + more skills than I have
- Google Cloud Datastore: is suitable for structured data of about this size, and has a baked-in JSON API, but doesn't do aggregates (so I couldn't support my "total spending" queries above)
- Google BigTable: can definitely do data of this size, can do aggregates, could build my own API using App Engine? Might need to convert data to hbase to import.
- Google BigQuery: fast at aggregating, would need to roll my own API as with BigTable, easy to import data

I'm wondering if there's a generic solution for my needs above. If not, I'd also be grateful for any advice on the best setup for hosting this data and providing a JSON API.

**Update**: Seems that BigQuery and Cloud SQL support SQL-like queries, but Cloud SQL may not be big enough (see comments) and BigQuery gets expensive very quickly, because you're paying by the query, so isn't ideal for a public web app. Datastore is good value, but doesn't do aggregates, so I'd have to pre-aggregate and have multiple tables.

Comment: Is Cloud SQL an option here?  Sizing FAQ - https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps

Comment: @SolomonDuskis Thanks. It does look like it would be big enough :) Is it likely to be performant on a dataset this size? Or is the answer (as with Postgres) "you won't know until you try with real data"?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm more of a Cloud Bigtable guy, myself.  Let me see if I can get someone from Cloud SQL to chime in.

Comment: I'm not completely sure Cloud SQL is big enough, actually - the Cloud SQL docs recommend that your dataset fits into RAM, and the biggest machine available has 104 GB RAM.

Comment: Regarding performance, it's workload dependent. As you mentioned earlier, you'd need to try it with real data. Also MySQL 5.7 now has native JSON support; that might be useful in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud SQL is likely sufficient for your needs. It certainly is capable of handling 200GB, especially if you use Cloud SQL Second Generation.

They only reason why a conventional database like MySQL (the database Cloud SQL uses) might not be sufficient is if your queries are very complex and  not indexed. I recommend you try Cloud SQL, and if the performance isn't sufficient, try ensuring you have sufficient indexes (hint: use the [EXPLAIN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to see how the queries are being executed).

If your queries cannot be indexed in a useful way, or your queries are so cpu intensive that they are slow regardless of indexing, you might want to graduate up to BigQuery. BigQuery is parallelised so that it can handle pretty much as much data as you throw at it, however it isn't optimized for real-time use and isn't as conveneint as Cloud SQL's "MySQL in a box".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). It's JSON, REST, cloud, distributed, quick on aggregate queries and so on. It may or may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks! is it likely to cope ok with this much data?

Comment: it's designed to run in a cloud (elastic cluster). It can dynamically scale up by spawning more nodes. Obviously, this requires architects who know how to implement such a service (say, on AWS). I've used it in a small project but I had to study the clustering aspect. I don't work for them so all I can/want to say is that I don't know of any upper limit. It depends on how much money/nodes you throw at it.

Comment: Get it for free, study some tutorials then test it with procedurally generated data on a Desktop PC or similar setup. It would take about 2-3 workdays to study and test a very simple setup with 10-100 GB of test data. Point straight to what you need, ignore all the other features or it'll take up far too much time to study for a quick technological feasability/stress test.

Comment: Read more about it here: [ES Blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-sizing-elasticsearch)

Comment: Here's another [good blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-storage-the-true-story) about a 83-168 TB setup...

Comment: Thanks very much - will do what you say!